# python how to crawl data generated by cgi

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Python to do some web crawling.

But I find out that the data I wanted was generated by a wen containing cgi in the end, sorry for my poor experience in web crawling, I find it pretty hard to get the data i wanted.

I set the headers, cookies.and the original location web should be `"www.xxxxx.com/cgi-bin/gameinfo_fcgi?a=0&b=1"`.

So I tried `requests.post` the data after `cgi`?, But I only got response 403.

Comment: Hey, please give the real url you want to crawl

Comment: Here is the real url "http://imgcache.qq.com/gc/gamecenterV2/dist/index/upcoming/upcoming.html".But it may need a login account

Comment: That URL returns an error: needs a login